# Append extra text to a bound textblock in winrt universal application

Tags: c#, binding, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount}" />
```

I have this text block, it simply shows a number what ever I bind.
What I want is that it could append 'AED' before the bindings. Mean if 4.00 is bound, it would show this:

AED 4.00

If I don't want to create another textblock and use it for AED and don't want to change the value of binding to 'AED 4.00' from '4.00', then is there a way to do this kind of thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement `IValueConverter` and use it in your XAML for converting the `double` value to `string.Format("AED {0}", value);`

Take a look at this [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/office/office365/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)

Comment: It is working great, but I want something like GreenEyedAndy answer, but his answer is not working right now. I'll mark it as answer if his solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**For WPF applications use this**:

Simply put a StringFormat to the Binding

```
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat=AED {0}}" />
```

Comment: Unknown member 'StringFormat' on element 'Binding'

Comment: Sorry Yawar, I didn't realize the tag "windows-phone-8.1". StringFormat isn't supported by this.